# Spark cast default value

Tags: apache-spark

i am doing an operation where I am casting columns to their data type.
Col(c).cast(datatype)

When the cast fails it converts to null. Is there a way to set that as a default value . Such that when cast fails it returns error than null ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function "coalesce" can be used:

```
val df = Seq("1", "k").toDF("value")
df
  .select(coalesce(col("value").cast(IntegerType), lit(5)))
```